# How redirect without header in php?

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have `controllerLoginUsu.php` :

```
<?php

require "dao/daoLoginUsu.php";  

class LoginUsuario{

    public function setDatos($aInput) {

        $obj = json_decode($aInput, true);

       $Dao = new daoLoginUsuario();
       $Dao->setDataDato($obj);

       $msj = $Dao->setDataDato($obj);


      session_start();
      if ($msj === 'si') {
          $_SESSION['msj'] = "si";
          return $msj;
          header("http://localhost:8080/formulario_web/formulario/formulario_lazos.php");
          exit; 

      }
   } 
}
?>
```

After I start session and return $msj I need redirect but with header don't work. some other solution to this case?

Sorry my english.

Comment: You must send header before return. And the header should be `header("Location: http://....")`

Comment: Maybe client-side JavaScript is an option for you: location = "http://localhost:8080/formulario_web/formulario/formulario_lazos.php";

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect without header, try this:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "location.replace('classes.php?add=sucess')";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: This is actually a very nasty way of doing the same thing as a `header()` as the whole page gets built->sent to the browser->then the DOM is built by the browser->AND THEN EVERYTHING IS THROWN WAY. **very wasteful**

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the Location.

try:

```
header("Location: http://localhost:8080/formulario_web/formulario/formulario_lazos.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

You never ever reach the header() call:

```
 return $msj;  // terminate function IMMEDIATELY
 header("http://localhost:8080/formulario_web/formulario/formulario_lazos.php"); // never reached
```

`return` should come **AFTER** `header()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually a mixture of 2 of the below

If you are issuing a `header()` you dont want to `return` anything as you are forcing the loading of a new form. The `return` will of course stop execution of this method and in your case the header will then not even get executed.

Also you forgot to add the `location:` part of the `header()` statement.

So

```
if ($msj === 'si') {
    $_SESSION['msj'] = "si";
    header("Location: http://localhost:8080/formulario_web/formulario/formulario_lazos.php");
    exit; 
  }
```